# Como enviar un archivo a un correo

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, archivo, email

Como puedo adjuntar un archivo al enviar un correo por medio de asp.net mvc.

Esta función es la que recibe el archivo y el correo:

```
private string notificarCorreo(HttpPostedFileBase archivoPDF, string Correo)
        {
            UtilidadesController u = new UtilidadesController();

            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            try
            {
                Mail mail = new Mail();

                mail.Subject = "Correo envio PDF Prueba";

                mail.Body = "Hola :)";

                mail.Para.Add(Correo);

                u.EnviarCorreo(mail);

                return "Se envio correo";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "Error al enviar correo";
            }
        }
```

Y para mandar el correo tengo otra donde ya tengo todas las credenciales

```
public JsonResult EnviarCorreo(Mail mail)
        {
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            string correos = string.Join(",", mail.Para);
            try
            {
                SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com", 587);

                smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("", "");
                smtpClient.Port = 587;
                smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

                MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();

                mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("", "");

                foreach (string p in mail.Para)
                {
                    mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(p));
                }
                foreach (string cc in mail.Copia)
                {
                    mailMessage.CC.Add(cc);
                }

                mailMessage.To.Clear(); //  <----------------------------------------------------
                mailMessage.CC.Clear(); // enviar correo de confirmación a reasignar solicitud
                // <--------------------------------------------

                mailMessage.Subject = mail.Subject;

                mailMessage.Body += mail.Body;

                mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

                smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Correo enviado a: " + correos + " - exitoso.");
                return Json(new { result = "success" });

                //ViewBag.Message = "Your Message submitted successfully. " +
                //" We will contact you shortly. Thank You";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Correo enviado a: " + correos + " - fallido. Error: " + ex.Message);
                return Json(new { result = "error" });
                //ViewBag.Message = ex.Message.ToString();
            }

            //return View();
        }
```

Y así es como me llega:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para adjuntar un archivo al correo en ASP.NET MVC, debes agregar el archivo como un objeto adjunto al objeto MailMessage antes de enviar el correo. Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

1. Agrega un nuevo parámetro a la función notificarCorreo que reciba el archivo a adjuntar:

   ```
   private string notificarCorreo(HttpPostedFileBase archivoPDF, string Correo)
   ```
2. Dentro de la función, crea un objeto Attachment a partir del archivo adjunto:

   ```
   Attachment archivoAdjunto = new Attachment(archivoPDF.InputStream, archivoPDF.FileName);
   ```
3. Crea un objeto MailMessage como lo estás haciendo actualmente:

   ```
    MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
    mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("", "");
    mailMessage.Subject = mail.Subject;
    mailMessage.Body = mail.Body;
    mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
   ```
4. Agrega el archivo adjunto al objeto MailMessage:

   ```
    mailMessage.Attachments.Add(archivoAdjunto);
   ```
5. Envía el correo electrónico como lo estás haciendo actualmente.

---

A continuación, la función completa notificarCorreo con el código necesario para adjuntar un archivo:

```
private string notificarCorreo(HttpPostedFileBase archivoPDF, string Correo)
{
    UtilidadesController u = new UtilidadesController();

    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    try
    {
        Mail mail = new Mail();

        mail.Subject = "Correo envio PDF Prueba";
        mail.Body = "Hola :)";
        mail.Para.Add(Correo);

        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("", "");
        mailMessage.Subject = mail.Subject;
        mailMessage.Body = mail.Body;
        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

        Attachment archivoAdjunto = new Attachment(archivoPDF.InputStream, archivoPDF.FileName);
        mailMessage.Attachments.Add(archivoAdjunto);

        foreach (string p in mail.Para)
        {
            mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(p));
        }
        foreach (string cc in mail.Copia)
        {
            mailMessage.CC.Add(cc);
        }

        mailMessage.To.Clear();
        mailMessage.CC.Clear();

        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com", 587);
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("", "");
        smtpClient.Port = 587;
        smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);

        return "Se envio correo";    }    catch (Exception ex)    {
            return "Error al enviar correo"; }}
```

Recuerda que debes llamar a esta función pasándole el archivo adjunto como primer parámetro y el correo como segundo parámetro.